# How to implement a service in Xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, mqtt

using Xamarin and Mqtt and my mqtt client m2mqtt is unable to maintain a connection throughout the android lifecycle.

Activity life cycle will cause problems if your process needs to stay alive after the activity has paused or stopped (phone sleeps, user switches apps then comes back)

The idea of using a service is that it will remain intact regardless of where the activity is in the life cycle.

Can anyone show me how to implement a service.

Answer (score 2):

OK,

It's very easy and really kind of cool.

I got the info I needed to figure this out here [c# corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understand-bound-service-using-xamarin-with-visual-studio-20152/)

a lot of times when I need a layman's description csharp corner isn't bad I used their example pretty close to how they portrayed it I just want to help you to understand how to use it

You need 3 classes 
1. the service itself (we'll call it service)
2. service binder (serviceBinder)
3. service connection (serviceConnection)

I'll show you mine next (this is working), I was designing a bound service hence you will see in the names instead of service it's called boundService.  However, after doing this I found out that a start service works exactly the same way you just start it different the classes are the same.

You need android.app.

So first we need the service it extends :Service (important)

```
using Android.App

[Service]
class MqttBoundService : Service
{
    private MqttBoundServiceBinder binder;
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        binder = new MqttBoundServiceBinder(this);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnBind() method start from BoundService", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Bound Service is started", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        return binder;
    }
    public override bool OnUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "OnUnBind() Method Called from BoundService.cs", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        return base.OnUnbind(intent);
    }
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Bound Service Destroyed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
```

The toast is there just so you know whats happening in case your service is getting destroyed when you didn't want it too.

Ok now we need the service binder (Extends Binder important)

```
  class MqttBoundServiceBinder : Binder
{
    MqttBoundService service;
    public MqttBoundServiceBinder(MqttBoundService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

now we need the connection and this is where the heavy lifting takes place.  I am still new to this but it looks like you want to put the methods here that need to outlive the activity life cycle.

```
class MqttBoundServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
{
    public Connection connect { get; private set; }


    public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnServiceConnected() Method called");


    }
    public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnServiceDisConnected() Method called");
    }

    public Connection Connect()
    {
        connect = new Connection(Utility.data, Utility.cdata);
        return connect;
    }


}
```

in the method Connect I instantiate my Connection object the parameters here are security certs but that's not important.  I also have a property with get; set; that I set to my object so I can access the mqtt connection in my OnRestart() and OnResume() functions of my activity.

I was having problems with resources being diverted by android before I did this and that doesn't happen now.

Not sure if it matters but this is my OnRestart()

```
if (serviceConnection.connect == null)
        {
            DoBindService();
            connect = serviceConnection.Connect();
        }
        else
        {
            connect = serviceConnection.connect;
        }
```

Oh I forgot how to tell you how to start it OK for me I am doing a bound service this means that after all the activities (or clients) that are using it are destroyed the service is destroyed.

So to start a bound service first create a class level variable for the connection (in the activity -- it is referenced in my OnStart() above).  Also once you do this you can call the methods from this class (really cool)

```
MqttBoundServiceConnection serviceConnection = new mqttBoundServiceConnection();
```

Then we need a method in the activity called DoBindService

```
private void DoBindService()
    {
        var BoundServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MqttBoundService));
        BindService(BoundServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
    }
```

in the OnCreate() for the activity add

```
DoBindService();
```

I hope this help someone it helped me once I figured it out :)